# Python 3.x - Slightly Precise Optical Character Recognition. What should I use?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library, ocr, python-tesseract

```py
import time
# cv2.cvtColor takes a numpy ndarray as an argument
import numpy as nm
import pytesseract
# importing OpenCV
import cv2

from PIL import ImageGrab, Image

bboxes = [(1469, 1014, 1495, 1029)]


def imToString():
    # Path of tesseract executable
    pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'D:\Program Files (x86)\Tesseract-OCR' + chr(92) + 'tesseract.exe'
    while (True):
        for box in bboxes:
            # ImageGrab-To capture the screen image in a loop.
            # Bbox used to capture a specific area.
            cap = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=box)

            # Converted the image to monochrome for it to be easily
            # read by the OCR and obtained the output String.
            tesstr = pytesseract.image_to_string(
                cv2.cvtColor(nm.array(cap), cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY), lang='eng', config='digits')  # ,lang='eng')
            cap.show()
            #input()
            time.sleep(5)
            print(tesstr)

    # Calling the function


imToString()
```

It captures an image like this:
[image: IMG]
It isn't always two digits it can be one or three digits too.
Pytesseract returns values like: `asi` and `oli`
So, **which Image To Text (`OCR`) Algorithm should I use for this problem?** And, how to use that? I need a very precise value in this example it's 53 so the output should be around 50.

Comment: I think part of your question is maybe missing. There doesn't seem to be any indication of what you are talking about.

Comment: My main question is: Which Image To Text (`OCR`) Algorithm should I use for this problem?

Comment: Huh? You need a very precise value so 50 is good enough for 53? Nothing makes sense here. Please show some other examples of what you might capture so we can infer if the font varies, or the colour or the size or...

Comment: The size, the color, the font, the background is the same.

Comment: Cool, that makes it easier. You can probably use **OpenCV**'s *"template matching"* if you capture a sample of each digit.

Comment: That's cool! I've used it before! You made me solve my project easier!! Thanks!